# Store error using React.js - TypeError: Object(...) is not a function react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im trying to do the store of my SPA. I made the reducers of each thing i will need, but when i rendered the page i received this message

TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
Module../src/redux/store.js
C:/Users/Mycomputer/Desktop/Projects/React/2020_03_29_workshop/src/redux/store.js:13

> 13 | export default createStore(rootReducers,composeWithDevtools(applyMiddleware(thunk)))

**reducers.js**

```
import { GET_ALL_POSTS, GET_ALL_SPECIALITIES, GET_ALL_COURSES, GET_ALL_TEACHERS,
    GET_POST, GET_SPECIALITY, GET_LESSON, GET_COURSE } from "./actions"

export const postReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    if(action.type === GET_ALL_POSTS){
        return {
            ...state,
            posts: action.posts
        }
    }

    if(action.type === GET_POST){
        return {
            ...state,
            post: action.post
        }
    }
    return state
}

export const specialityReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    if(action.type === GET_ALL_SPECIALITIES){
        return {
            ...state,
            specialities: action.specialities
        }
    }

    if(action.type === GET_SPECIALITY)
        return {
            ...state,
            speciality: action.speciality
        }

    return state
}

export const courseReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    if (action.type === GET_ALL_COURSES){
        return {
            ...state,
            courses: action.courses
        }
    }
    if (action.type === GET_COURSE){
        return {
            ...state,
            course: action.course
        }
    }

    return state
}

export const teacherReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    if(action.type === GET_ALL_TEACHERS){
        return {
            ...state,
            teachers: action.teachers
        }
    }

    return state
}

export const lessonReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    if (action.type === GET_LESSON){
        return {
            ...state,
            lesson: action.lesson
        }
    }
    return state
}
```

**store.js**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { composeWithDevtools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { postReducer, 
    specialityReducer, 
    courseReducer, 
    teacherReducer, 
    lessonReducer 
} from './reducers'



export default createStore(combineReducers({postReducer, specialityReducer, courseReducer, teacherReducer, lessonReducer}),composeWithDevtools(applyMiddleware(thunk)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass object to combineReducers and give name before all reducers.
combineReducers({ reducerName: reducerFunction });